# csh: Changing path in non-interactive login

Tags: scripting, path, csh

I want this:

```
$ ssh nopathcsh@lo 'echo $path'
/usr/local/sbin /usr/local/bin /usr/sbin /usr/bin /sbin /bin /usr/games /usr/local/games
```

To return this:

```
/usr/bin /bin
```

I have tried changing and removing `.login` and `.cshrc`, but that seems to have no effect. These seem only to have effect if the shell is interactive.

The user `nopathcsh` has `/bin/csh` as login shell.

Comment: Using `set path=(/usr/bin /bin)` in `~/.login` and `csh -l <<< 'echo $path'` works for me...?

Comment: How can I ask `ssh nopathcsh@lo 'echo $path'` to run `csh -l`?

Comment: I don't have csh as a login shell, so I was emulating it. If the `nopathcsh` user has csh as their login shell, then my assumption would be that ~/.login would be the right place.  But I wasn't sure, so I thought I'd check against what you had tested.

Comment: @JeffSchaller The `ssh nopathcsh@lo 'echo $path'` is non-optional and cannot be changed. You _can_ change `.ssh/*` or `.login/.cshrc` or `/etc/*`.

Comment: I suppose a more direct comment would be: what happens when you put `set path=(/usr/bin /bin)` in `~nopathcsh/.login`?

Comment: You have to use $PATH with uppercase.

Comment: @PersianGulf no you don't.

Answer (score 0):

It appears my `/bin/csh` is really `tcsh` and even when called as `/bin/csh` it thinks it should read `.tcshrc` (which baffles me: if I call `csh` I expect to get `csh` not `tcsh`).

Removing `.tcshrc` made it respect `.cshrc` (but not `.login`).

Comment: Interesting; my "csh" is "tcsh" also, and with a misleading ~/.tcshrc file and a correct ~/.login, .~/login still prevails in my testing.

Comment: I think we can conclude `csh` works in mysterious ways.

Comment: why are you expecting that? the tcsh(1) manpage clearly tells that `~/.tcshrc` will be tried first, no matter what the interpreter is called. `.login` will only be read by a login shell --ie a shell with its argv[0] starting with a dash. `ssh` will start such a "login shell" only when no command was given.

Comment: @mosvy I naively expected `tcsh` to be a drop-in replacement for `csh` when called as `csh`. I am happy that the incompatibility is at least documented.